# Unexpected output type

Tags: recursion, f#

I am doing practice with F#. I am trying to create a simple program capable to find me out a couple of prime numbers that, summed together, equal a natural number input. It is the Goldbach conjecture. A single couple of primes will be enough. We will assume the input to be a even number.

I first created a function to check if a number is prime:

```
let rec isPrime (x: int) (i: int) :bool =
    match x % i with
    | _ when float i > sqrt (float x)   -> true
    | 0                                 -> false
    | _                                 -> isPrime x (i + 1)
```

Then, I am trying to develop a function that (a) looks for prime numbers, (b) compare their sum with the input 'z' and (c) returns a tuple when it finds the two numbers. The function should not be correct yet, but I would get the reason behind this problem:

```
let rec sumPrime (z: int) (j: int) (k: int) :int * int =
    match isPrime j, isPrime k with
    | 0, 0 when j + k > z   -> (0, 0)
    | 0, 0                  -> sumPrime (j + 1) (k + 1)
    | _, 0                  -> sumPrime j (k + 1)
    | 0, _                  -> sumPrime (j + 1) k
    | _, _                  -> if j + k < z then
                                   sumPrime (j + 1) k
                               elif j + k = z then
                                   (j, k)
```

The problem: even if I specified that the output should be a tuple `:int * int` the compiler protests, claiming that the expected output should be of type `bool`. When in trouble, I usually refer to [F# for fun and profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/troubleshooting-fsharp/), that i love, but this time I cannot find out the problem. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: isPrime returns bools, you are matching ints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has three problems that I've spotted:

1. Your `isPrime` returns a `bool` (as you've specified), but your `match` expression in `sumPrime` is matching against integers (in F#, the Boolean value `false` is **not** the same as the integer value `0`). Your `match` expression should look like:

   ```
   match isPrime j, isPrime k with
   | false, false when j + k > z   -> (0, 0)
   | false, false                  -> ...
   | true,  false                  -> ...
   | false, true                   -> ...
   | true,  true                   -> ...
   ```
2. You have an `if...elif` expression in your `true, true` case, but there's no final `else`. By default, the final `else` of an `if` expression returns `()`, the `unit` type. So once you fix your first problem, you'll find that F# is complaining about a type mismatch between `int * int` and `unit`. You'll need to add an `else` condition to your final match case to say what to do if `j + k > z`.
3. You are repeatedly calling your `sumPrime` function, which takes three parameters, with just two parameters. That is perfectly legal in F#, since it's a curried language: calling `sumPrime` with two parameters produces the type `int -> int * int`: a function that takes a single `int` and returns a tuple of `int`s. But that's not what you're actually trying to do. Make sure you specify a value for `z` in all your recursive calls.

With those three changes, you should probably see your compiler errors go away.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that out. Your answer is really enlightening!